# How to catch the exit signal raised by Py_Finalize()?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am using *pybind11* to embed python interpreter into C++ with `pybind11::scoped_interpreter guard{}`. I import my own module, run some functions, then exit the program. When the software exits, *pybind11* eventually calls `Py_Finalize()`. I want to catch the exit signal inside my python module to call some destructors, when `Py_Finalize()` called inside C++. How can I achieve that?

**C++ code:**

```
pybind11::scoped_interpreter guard{};
py::module my_module = py::module::import("my_module");
my_module.attr("my_function")(someData);
```

**python code** (*my_module.py*):

```
session.init()
def my_func(input):
    output = session.foo(input)
    return output

#how to catch exit signal to run this function
def run_at_exit(session):
    session.finalize()
```

Comment: Do you mean something like: https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html?